# Is there a word for the feeling you get when you reflect on a past relationship in which you are now strangers?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm not sure if there is a word to describe the feeling I get when I think about a past relationship were we once were deeply connected and now we are simply strangers.

I was hoping to get some words that can express this feeling.

Comment: Sorry about that, but perhaps it is up to you to tell us how you feel, we can't know that. It could be happiness, sadness, nostalgia, remorse, even guilt; or various feelings at different times.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I realize now I didn't give much detail in terms of what I am feeling. It is close to nostalgia with a bit of sadness that its over but happiness that it happened.

Comment: Still unclear, sorry. "It happened" - started or ended? The emotional world is complex. A relationship may have been wonderful, but went sour, so the happiness could refer to either. A relationship can end for many reasons, some purely practical.

Comment: angst, relief, melancholy, giddiness, sorrow...  Your question is unclear.

Comment: The question is not unclear: it just shows lack of basic research i.e. words which approximate the feeling which for some reason do not work. [...not to mention that many people confuse "feelings" with emotions.]

Comment: You now feel alienated from the person. Alienation.

Answer (score 2):

**estranged**

from your question...

> "...now we are simply **strangers**."

[From Merriam Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/estranged)

> having lost former closeness and affection : in a state of ***alienation*** from a previous close or familial relationship

Ex.

> ...now we are *estranged*

Comment: Perhaps I should not have replied to this, but in the past I have been scolded for posting answers in the comment section. ...still a little confused about what constitutes a close-worthy Q for lack of research, or lack of clarity.

Comment: Me too.  I was even suspended from ze ozzer forem for over-posting and misinformation. That said, I think estranged or alienated works well here.

Answer (score 0):

**[Nostalgia](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nostalgia)**

> a wistful desire to return in thought or in fact to a former time in one's life, to one's home or homeland, or to one's family and friends; a sentimental yearning for the happiness of a former place or time
>
> *A nostalgia for his college days.*

Answer (score 0):

> It is close to nostalgia with a bit of sadness that its over but
>   happiness that it happened.

As in:

> Overall, I felt **enriched** when reflecting on our past relationship.

**enrich**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/enriched)

2. To make fuller, more meaningful, or more rewarding